# how to upgrade android sdk version by command line

Tags: android, flutter

i am new to Android development and i want to upgrade my android sdk version from 32.1.0-rc1 to 33.0.0-rc2.
And i have another question what is the difference between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion on the file build.gradle on flutter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For update sdk by command LINE, see this gist:

https://gist.github.com/srayhunter/4bce340b62109b5bae43

`sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.2" "platforms`;

About the difference ...

The compileSdkVersion is the version of the API the app is compiled against. This means you can use Android API features included in that version of the API.
And the targetSdkVersion indicate that you have tested your app on the version you specify.

Comment: sdkmanager: command not found Despite i download from tools on Android sdk command line tools

Comment: you install command line tools? https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools

Comment: yes i have this error Warning: Failed to find package build-tools;33.0.3   i don't  khnow the cause of it